# Can Getch (or something similar) be made to accept backspaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, backspace, getch

I am using the following function, getPass() for a secure password entry:

```py
def getPass():
    password = ''
    while True:
        x = getch.getch()
        # x = msvcrt.getch().decode("utf-8")
        if x == '\r' or x == '\n':
            break
        print('*', end='', flush=True)
        password += x
    return password
```

However, the one catch is that backspaces are not accepted except as new characters:

Backspaces in real life show up like this: ( "|" symbol used for reference)

Before:

> ••••|

After:

> ••• |

But when I execute `getpass()`, it shows up in the console like:

Before:
`****|`

and then you hit backspace, what should become

> `*** |`

actually becomes

> `****|*`

(Notice the extra star).

Perhaps I should just leave the solution as `print('Type your password:\n(Backspace not accepted: Press Enter to redo))` putting the user into a loop, but this is very annoying to 21st century users.

Comment: If x is a backspace, then your code should erase the last asterisk (by printing an actual backspace, then a space, then another backspace) and _not_ append x onto the password.

Comment: @JohnGordon
Meaning that the line:

```if x == '\r' or x == '\n':

            break```

Would substitute `\r` and `\n` would be substituted correctly , and when the "confirm password" field checked it, it would be valid without the backspace?

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not using the standard `getpass` module, that does all of this already?

Comment: @jasonharper
I actually used an answer to this question posted by Mostafa Hassan. I never saw the unedited getpass module. Thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll upvote you as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the standard getpass() module.

```
from getpass import getpass
def getPass():
    password = getpass.getpass('Enter Your Password\n>>>')
    return password
password = getpass()
```